# "PXE-E61: Media test failure" installation boot problem with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, restart

For the first time in my Life I am installing an OS.
I installed it properly using a USB. After the installation, it asked to restart. On restarting, two things are happening:

1. I restart with the pendrive
   It is asking me to select one of the four options-

   ```
   Try Ubuntu without installation
   Install Ubuntu
   OEM install (for manufacturers)
   Check disk for defects
   ```
2. I restart without the pendrive
   It says- 
   `PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
   PXE-M0F: Reboot and Select proper Boot device`.

Please help!!

Comment: What drive did install to during the installation?

Comment: The HDD was not partitioned since it was new. During the installation, it did not ask for a drive.

Comment: It sounds like it installed to the Pen Drive - go to `Try Ubuntu without installation`, click `Try Ubuntu`, and open a terminal, and run `sudo fdisk -l`. Please then add the output to your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/M0rX8F6

Comment: ..if you decide re-formatting the HDD, you might want to change the partition table to MBR..

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the installation media(pendrive) and then change the boot order in bios to HDD as the first option.
- Save the changes and then reboot your pc.

Comment: The HDD is the first option already

Comment: how did you installed ubuntu?

Comment: downloaded the iso from the website, prepared a bootable usb, then it got booted automatically, installed it, then it asked to restart, I restarted first with pd, and then without(after which what happened is given above)and thus, now it doesn't work.

Comment: boot from the bootable ubuntu pendrive,click on try ubuntu.Open up the gparted partition editor,take a screenshot of it and then upload it to `imgur.com` after that post the link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/LXgSasP

Comment: I advice you to delete ext2 and lvmp2 partitions and reinstall ubuntu. don't encrypt your partition,it was so hard to resize and also install ubuntu on a ext4 filesystem not ext2.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: unmount lvm2pv and then delete it.Did you able to get into chat?

Comment: did it, not working yet

Comment: Did you deleted the lvm partition?

Comment: Change uefi mode to legacy mode in bios.

Answer (score 1):

Install the OS again on the hard drive and test to load again without the USB when it asks to remove all media to restart as you already have the first option set on BIOS to be the HDD to load.

Answer (score 1):

thankyou SO much for all your inputs!!
Figured out the problem
-I had booted Ubuntu via UEFI(Which is supposed to be there to support HDD greater than 2 TB). But my HDD is only 1 TB. Hence, the OS must not have installed properly.
-I then re-installed it in the Legacy mode, and now, it works just fine!

This is my first experience with Open Source stuff! And I really, really LOVE the community over here! Your prompt replies motivated me to not give up so easily! Thankyou so much once again!!!

Comment: ...a good tip; could use some clarification. My issue was caused by boot loading initially using UEFI from the bootable USB rather than Legacy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it did not install properly...

Try running the install again, but selecting 'Something Else', and creating:

- A `/` partition *(that contains all the stuff for the system, so needs to be somewhere above 20GB/20000MB in size)*
- And a `/home` partition *(where all the user's stuff goes on the computer)*, which can be large or small as you like, though you would probably want as large as possible.

Make sure that your hard drive is selected for the bootloader and for partitioning - it is likely to be `/dev/sda`

Like this *(not the same - e.g. both <kbd>Format</kbd> boxes may be ticked etc)*:

[image: something else]

Comment: not working yet :(

Comment: is it something to do with uefi and legacy mode?

Comment: it could be :-( - if so, please add the hardware and any additional error details to your question.

Comment: Added it to the description

Comment: Hey, I just read that UEFI booting is only for HDD greater than 2 TB. I booted my OS in UEFI. I want to now boot it in Legacy. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: VICTORY!!! :D :D

Comment: It worked then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Old laptop with new Debian installer, I had to go into BIOS and change to UEFI and then boot with USB into rescue mode to reinstall Grub installer to `/dev/sda` and it worked great.
Hope that helps.
SSF